# How to hide Aptana start page on Eclipse?

Tags: windows, eclipse, aptana

How to make it not appear when I open Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, might not be the same thing you are after, but have you tried

Window -> Preferences -> Aptana -> My Aptana -> My Aptana Options : Never display after startup?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Aptana start page is a [welcome page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro.htm), you could try and follow [that thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg31656.html) recommending:

- looking for a `plugin_customization.ini` file
- adding:

```
    org.eclipse.ui/showIntro=false
    org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_PROGRESS_ON_STARTUP=false
```

Comment: I only found 2 files with this name. None of them were in folders related to APTANA. After the modification the behavior didn't change